# How do I hide a button in on one Platform in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an button that starts a function that I don't want to start on Android but not on UWP, iOS or macOS. How do I mark the button to be only displayed when the OS isn't Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple code snippet

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{
    //make your button invisible
}
```